# jquery templates iterate on value, not number of keys

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Using the jquery template plugin is pretty straighforward, but i'm facing an issue quite simple to explain.

I'd like to iterate in my template based on the value of one key I get;

for example num_lines : 15

```
{{each (var i = 0; i < ${num_lines}; i++)}}
poet
{{/each}}
```

While logic is ok, it does'nt do the trick. Any idea where i'm wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: i didnt know you could use a for loop like that inside each. where did you see something liek this used?

Comment: well that's sort of the point here, i'm trying to firgure out a way to do it ;)

Comment: you are trying to write the word poet 15 times?

Comment: don't bother about the word, but yep, that's the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`{{each}}`](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/) expects some sort of collection. You will need to build up a collection from your count to use it.

You could simply create a helper function for your template and pass it in the options parameter. Here's a sample [jsFiddle jQuery template that uses an each-friendly custom function](http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/LNbHE/). You simply give it the word you want repeated and how many times and `{{each}}` does the work for you.

#### Template

```
<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <ul>
    {{each(i, prop) $item.makeArrayForEach("poet", $data.someInteger)}}
        <li>${prop}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var makeArrayForEach = function (word, size) {
    var i, result = [];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result.push(word);
    }
    return result;
};

$("#itemTemplate").tmpl(yourObject, {
    makeArrayForEach: makeArrayForEach
}).appendTo($(".results"));
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think each is meant to use in this fashion. the only thing I can think of is doing:

javascript:

```
 var poet = [{
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"},
         {Poet:"poet"}
    }];
```

HTML:

```
{{each Poet}}
       ${$value}
{{/each}}
```